# ERROR: only static member can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter

I am trying to push the new route using the following code -

```
void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MyHomePage(
          title: title,
          vidUrl: vidUrl, //contains my video url
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then in MyHomePage route I want to access this forwarded video url. This is my code below

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.vidUrl}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String vidUrl;

  //MyHomePage({this.title, this.vidUrl});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(title: title, vidUrl: vidUrl);

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String title; 
  String vidUrl;

  _MyHomePageState({this.title, this.vidUrl});

  //here i'm getting error of only static members can be accessed in vidUrl variable...
  final VideoControllerWrapper videoControllerWrapper = VideoControllerWrapper(
    DataSource.network(vidUrl, 
        displayName: title),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: NeekoPlayerWidget(
            onSkipPrevious: () {
              print("skip");
              videoControllerWrapper.prepareDataSource(
                DataSource.network(
                    vidUrl,
                    displayName: title),
              );
            },
            videoControllerWrapper: videoControllerWrapper,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("share");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting the error of only static member can be accessed, if I change it to static then another error happens. The video isn't loading at all. I guess I'm using the variables in wrong way. Please help me in this with any better approach to achieve this. 
**All I want to do is to play the video in MyHomePage route using the forwarded link from another page.**

If anyone can help me in this, it would mean world to me! **Thanks for your time**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `widget.` prefix needed to access the variables passed to the constructor of a Stateful Widget from its State class. Try this:

```
final VideoControllerWrapper videoControllerWrapper = VideoControllerWrapper(
  DataSource.network(
    widget.vidUrl, 
    displayName: widget.title
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String title;
  String vidUrl;
  final VideoControllerWrapper videoControllerWrapper;
  _MyHomePageState({@required this.title,@required this.vidUrl}) {
    videoControllerWrapper = VideoControllerWrapper(
      DataSource.network(vidUrl, displayName: title),
    );
  }
```

Try to initialize it in the constructor

Comment: He is receiving the variables from the Stateless Widget's constructor. Initialising them in the same class wouldn't make sense.